# Android Dialog curved edges

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I have implemented a custom Dialog in android. The custom view contains curved edges but not the Dialog itself. I want this Dialog to get the shape of curved edges. How it can be done?

[image]

As you can see, the curved edges are not actually curve. 
Any help or idea would be highly appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Thanks everyone.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are two possible reasons that make your custom view like this:

1. You forget set the dialog's background transparent first;
2. The custom background image's corner part is not set transparent.(you can set it transparent and save it with png format.)

Comment: About your second point:
The custom view does not consist of that white part on the edges. it's the default dialog's edges.
let me try with setting the dialogs background to transparent.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> A dialog is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or
>   enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is
>   normally used for modal events that require users to take an action
>   before they can proceed.

You need to create a custom dialog in Android.

1. Create a custom dialog layout (XML file).
2. Attach the layout to Dialog.

Please check below Demo Links

1. [Android Custom Dialog Tutorial](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-custom-dialog-tutorial.html)
2. [How to create custom Dialog Box in android ?](https://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/how-to-create-custom-dialog-box-in-android/)